# How to force bash to do variable expansion on a string?

Tags: bash, variable-expansion

I have read a line of bash code from the file, and I want to send it to log. To make it more useful, I'd like to send the variable-expanded version of the line.

I want to expand only shell variables. I don't want the pipes to be interpreted, nor I don't want to spawn any side processes, like when expanding a line with `$( rm -r /)`.

I know that variable expansion is very deeply woven into the bash. I hope there is a way to perform *just* expansion, without any side effects, that would come from pipes, external programs and - perhaps - here-documents.

Maybe there is something like `eval`?

```
#!/bin/bash
linenr=42
line=`sed "${linenr}q;d" my-other-script.sh`
shell-expand $line >>mylog.log
```

I want a way to expand only the shell variables. 
if `x=a`, `a="example"` then I want the following expansions:

`echo $x` should be `echo a`.

`echo ${a}` should be `echo example`

`touch ${!x}.txt` should be `touch example.txt`

`if [ (( ${#a} - 6  )) -gt 10 ]; then echo "Too long string"` should be `if [ 1 -gt 10 ]; then echo "Too long string"`

`echo "\$a and \$x">/dev/null` should be `echo "\$a and \$x>dev/null"`

Answer (score 2):

For those arriving five years later, and, although it is not the best answer to the OP's *problem*, an answer to the question is as follows. Bash can do [indirect](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) parameter expansion:

```sh
some_param=a
a=b
echo ${!some_param}
echo $BASH_VERSION
# 5.0.18(1)-release
```

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right, it is very dangerous to use the bash.
In fact your command suffers from your problem.

Let us discuss your script in detail:

```
#!/bin/bash
line=`sed "${42}q;d" my-other-script.sh`
shell-expand $line >>mylog.log
```

The sed may produce many lines of output, so it is misleading to use the name `line`.

Then you did not quote $line, this may have obscure effects:

```
$ x='| grep x'
$ ls -l $x
ls: cannot access |: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access grep: No such file or directory
-rw-rw-r-- 1 foo bar 34493 Nov 19 18:51 x
$
```

In this case the pipe is not executed, but passed to the program ls.
If you have untrusted input, it is very hard to program a robust shell script.

Using eval is evil - I would never suggest using it, especially for such a purpose!

An alternative way would be in perl, iterate over the $ENV array and replace all env keys by the env values. This way you have more control over the things, which may happen.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I already know that Bash's eval don't fit, otherwise I wouldn't have asked this question. Actually I was subconsciously thinking about `R`'s eval (and `R` is a mostly functional programming language, so there are hardly any side-effects associated with evaluation). Sorry for misinformation.

Comment: `sed "${42}q;d" my-other-script.sh` was a typo; it should be: `sed "42q;d" my-other-script.sh` or better yet - the form I put on my answer. I understand, that this `sed` invocation can only produce a single line.

Comment: You could use two echos in a subcommand: `echo "$(echo "my username is $USER")"` but quoting must be done carefully.